# probability is equals to O(m)

Tags: graph, big-o, probability

Lets say n is the size of the network.

m is a function of n.

Make a subset of nodes from n nodes, probability of a node is p = O(m).

What does p=O(m) means, how do I make a subset from n nodes based on the given probability.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of a single node is O(m(n)). Therefore, there must be O(m(n) * n) nodes in the subset to satisfy this condition. This means that your subset size will scale proportionally with the product of your m function and the size of your set.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but my problem is how do you write a code to generate a subgraph based on the probability(which you are given is not a fixed value) p<= M* m(n) where M is a constant.

Comment: If you're talking about a subgraph as simply a collection of nodes from the original graph: assuming you have a list of nodes, you can do a random shuffle for the list of nodes, and return the top M*m(n)*n entries.

Comment: The problem is with the M(constant) which we don't know.